# Reusing User Controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to alter an existing WPF application and my lack of WPF experience (I'm WINFORMS) is making this difficult.

I've come across a situation where I need to reuse a UserControl and I'm not sure how to do this in terms of modifying the xaml. I'll explain.

UserControlA has the following code:

```
   <Grid Name="gdMain" Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <content:MonitorAlarmsPage />
    </Grid>
```

Now, "MonitorAlarmsPage" is an AXML document that defines another UserControl - UserControlB. This UserControl, once created has to persist for the lifetime of the application.

So, I could have many UserControlAs, but only ONE UserControlB.

I've created a static class that has an appropriate UserControlB field which is updated when UserControlB is created, but how do I modify the `content:MonitorAlarmsPage` so that the content of the grid is replaced by the existing UserControlB as referenced in this static class and not by the XAML file that defines UserControlB? Can this actually be done? i.e. essentially, insert pre created user controls inside an  XAML page.

To make things a bit clearer, UserControlB is essentially a page that can sit inside another page. The page is complex and there is a massive overhead incurred when it is created and so must only be created once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is very different to WinForms, so you certainly have your work cut out for you. The basic idea for the solution to your problem is this. You'll need to add a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `MonitorAlarmsPage` control. This will enable you to data bind to this property from outside the control.. This property should be of a type of custom class that you define, that contains *all* of the properties required *in the inner control*.

The next stage is to develop a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that defines how WPF should display your custom class when it comes across an instance of it. In this `DataTemplate`, you declare your inner control, so that when WPF sees the custom class, it displays the inner control and sets the custom class as the `DataContext` for the inner control:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourCustomClass}">
    <YourControlsXmlNamespacePrefix:YourInnerControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally, you'll need to data bind your custom class (the `static` class) to the outer `UserControl`:

```
<content:MonitorAlarmsPage YourCustomClassProperty="{Binding YourStaticClass}" />
```

So just to be clear... this `static` class should be a data class, *not* a UI class. When using WPF, we manipulate data, not UI elements. We let the wonderful templating system generate the UI for us.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I'm still confused (well, less so than this morning). From your explanation - tell me if I'm wrong - you're suggesting still creating multiple UserControlBs but having each one load their properties from an attached (bound?) property which references my static class. Could this not be achieved simply by referencing in the InitializeComponent method of UserControlB, the static class property and therefore reading its properties there.... (p.s. running out of chars and there's more.....

Comment: One of the controls in UserControlB is a treeview -this could have 100k,200k or > entries (it's built up over time) and that's why it must only be created once. Even though it uses a single datasource, recreating the TreeView takes a helluva lot of time and therefore it's not good enough to simply 'copy' properties from one object to another.What I need is a way of 'plugging in' an existing instance of a UserControl or creating one if one cannot be found. This instance of UserControlB will not be shared, but there's such an overhead in its creation that once created it's kept.

Comment: Therefore, I suspect it's easier to achieve this in code as opposed to XAML. When UserControlA is created, it checks for the existence of UserControlB - if found it 'plugs it in.. ' (apologise for the waffle) otherwise it does what it's doing at the moment and loads the grid content from the XAML defining UserControlB

Comment: Really, I was making the point that when using WPF, we manipulate the data elements and not the UI elements. This adheres to the separation of concerns principle and improves the testability of our code. However, in your case, if you say that the length of time that the `TreeView` takes to populate its data is too long and you want to maintain one UI control, then you can do that... you'll just lose some ease of testing. If you don't have unit tests for your application, then it's not really a problem.